# Regex for an open SGML node that contains <p> , </p>, and <br /> tags

Tags: html, xml, regex, sgml

I have some SGML that I'm trying to clean up by adding closing tags to the opening ones. Right now, the document has a structure like this:

```
<CAT>
<NAME>Daniel
<COLOR>White
<DESC>Daniel is a white cat <p>He was born in July</p><br />He's super cute.<p><br />He does not have any siblings.
<COUNTRY>USA
</CAT>
```

So far I can match an open tag and capture the content as a group using this regexp: 
`<NAME>([^\\<]+)[^<]` if doesn't have any `<p>`, `</p>`, or `<br />` elements within the content area. 
But if i do 
`<DESC>([^\\<]+)[^<]`, the pattern matching stops right before the first `<p>`

The reason why I'm using `<` as the end of the pattern is because all the other open nodes don't have html elements that stop the matching

How can I make a regexp that matches the `<DESC>` node that includes `<p>`, `</p>`, `<br />` and ends before the `<COUNTRY>` node?

Comment: HTML / SGML is not a good candidate for parsing using regular expressions.

Comment: I can't seem to find a different way without writing a DTD, so I went with just trying to close the open tags and parsing it as XML using an actual XML parser. I'm open to suggestions and resources though.

Comment: If you have `<br/>`, you don't have SGML. SGML does not allow self-closing tags.

Comment: @DanielHaley ISO 8879 Technical Corrigendum 2 allows self-closing tags if either NETENABL IMMEDNET or NETENABL ALL is declared in the SHORTTAG start-tag options. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language#NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
<DESC>((?:</?p>|<br />|[^\\<])+)
```

This allows these three tags to match and stops at the next `<` that doesn't belong to one of the three.

By the way, why aren't you allowing the backslash as a valid character?

Comment: @user1352544: Small update, I removed the trailing `[^<]` - it's not required and might break the regex if a `<br />` tag directly precedes the next `<COUNTRY>` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure about the backslash question. I'm pretty sure I can allow those, would it be `<DESC>((?:</?p>|<br />|[^<])+)` instead?